# Better way of joining rows based on same id

Tags: sql-server-2008

The problem I am trying to solve is to know how often the combination will occure of the same registrationid and the limitid values of 33 and 5.

These are a couple of rows I have in a SQL database table:

```
      id  limitid    registrationid 
---------------------------------------
     113       33              3712 
     114        5              3712 
     116       33              3713 
     117        5              3713 
    1428       33              3714 
    1434        5              3720
```

A RegistrationId can have 0, 1 or two values in this table.
I am looking for the case where the regsitrationId has two values and put the corresponding limitid's (together with the registrationid) in a result set, like:

```
    limitid1    limitid2    registrationid
------------------------------------------
          33           5             3712
```

To achieve that I use this sql code:

```
DECLARE @t TABLE(
    id int NOT NULL,
    regid int NOT NULL,
    limitid int not null
);
insert into @t
SELECT    Id,  RegistrationId, limitid
FROM      my-table
WHERE     (LimitId = 33) 
ORDER BY RegistrationId

DECLARE @t2 TABLE(
    id int NOT NULL,
    regid int NOT NULL,
    limitid int not null
);
insert into @t2
SELECT    Id,  RegistrationId, limitid
FROM      my-table
WHERE     (LimitId = 5) 
ORDER BY RegistrationId

declare @t3 Table(
    regid int NOT NULL,
    limitid1 int not null,
    limitid2 int not null
);
insert into @t3
SELECT     t1.RegId, t1.limitid, t2.limitid
FROM       @t as t1
join @t2 as t2
on t1.regid = t2.regid

select * from @t3
```

My question: is there a different/better way of achiving the same result?

thanks!

Comment: You should explain better what you are trying to do. I don't think it is very clear.

Comment: @FilipeSilva I have made edits to my question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not 100% sure i understand you completely, but you can achieve that output with:

```
SELECT t1.limitId AS limitid1,t2.limitId AS limitid2, t1.registrationID
FROM myTable t1
INNER JOIN myTable t2 ON t1.registrationID = t2.registrationID
WHERE t1.limitID = 33 
  AND t2.limitID = 5;
```

<kbd>[sqlfiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/9bbd9/2)</kbd>

This gives you the combinations of limitID1 and limitID2 and the registrationID's that are shared between them.

EDIT:

If you don't want to get every registrationID, you can get only the MIN(t1.registrationID):

```
SELECT t1.limitId AS limitid1,
       t2.limitId AS limitid2, 
       MIN(t1.registrationID) AS Num_Records
FROM myTable t1
INNER JOIN myTable t2 ON t1.registrationID = t2.registrationID
WHERE t1.limitID = 33 AND t2.limitID = 5
GROUP BY t1.limitId,t2.limitId
```

<kbd>[sqlfiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/9bbd9/8)</kbd>

Comment: Many thanks for the effort, but this is not what I want. I need one row with both the limitid's and the registrationId. Your result is two rows.

Comment: You had two rows in your expected result, so i assumed you wanted it like this. Then What do you want to have in the third column? The number of times it happens? Nothing? A random registrationID?

Comment: In one row i have: registrationid 3712, limitid = 33. In the second row I have registrationid 3712 and limitid =5 . In the resulting row I want to have 3 colomns: registrationid and both limitid's. Hope that helps explaining it.

Comment: I can't see what you mean by that. Can you edit the question and correct your desired output?

Comment: I added a possibility to get what you want.